# Get all childs od childs of (.....) childs of parentNode

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

Good morning, or in other words: "Hello World".

This may sound like a stupid beginners question but am not sure if I just missed something:

If in HTML you have a DIV with two children (say div as well)
you can say .childElementCount will result in 2.
To access them you can say .children[0] and children[1]

But, if the children also have children and those also have children.....
How can I determine the total amount of elements within a DOM Node?

Do I really need to check for "hasChildren" or is there an easy way to get all sub and sub-sub-elements for a specific dom element which I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` with `*` as it will select all the DOM elements inside it. Then count the elements using `.length` property.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("#parent *").length;
console.log(x);
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this quick response. But this works only w/ id, doesn't it?
But yes, I didn't think about querySelectorAll, I will check this option, thanks! EDIT: Sorry, you are right, was confudsed!

Comment: @David no, It will work with any selector. Maybe you might need to tweak it a little bit but yea it will work. Also if this answer helps then do mark it correct :)